# Having multiple issues for installation of Multiple version of Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-3.7

I have three versions of python

1. 3.9.11
2. 3.11.8
3. 3.12.2

I have installed all the versions.
Now when I am trying to check all the versions of python I installed using commands

```
py -0 #Doesn't Working
python3.9.11 -m venv app1 #its also not working
python --list #its also not working
```

```
python -h #shows this

C:\Users\91783>python -h
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options (and corresponding environment variables):
-b     : issue warnings about str(bytes_instance), str(bytearray_instance)
         and comparing bytes/bytearray with str. (-bb: issue errors)
-B     : don't write .pyc files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-d     : turn on parser debugging output (for experts only, only works on
         debug builds); also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
-h     : print this help message and exit (also -? or --help)
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
-I     : isolate Python from the user's environment (implies -E and -s)
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
-O     : remove assert and __debug__-dependent statements; add .opt-1 before
         .pyc extension; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-OO    : do -O changes and also discard docstrings; add .opt-2 before
         .pyc extension
-P     : don't prepend a potentially unsafe path to sys.path; also PYTHONSAFEPATH
-q     : don't print version and copyright messages on interactive startup
-s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
-S     : don't imply 'import site' on initialization
-u     : force the stdout and stderr streams to be unbuffered;
         this option has no effect on stdin; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
         when given twice, print more information about the build
-W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
         also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg
-x     : skip first line of source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd
-X opt : set implementation-specific option
--check-hash-based-pycs always|default|never:
         control how Python invalidates hash-based .pyc files
--help-env      : print help about Python environment variables and exit
--help-xoptions : print help about implementation-specific -X options and exit
--help-all      : print complete help information and exit
Arguments:
file   : program read from script file
-      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)
arg ...: arguments passed to program in sys.argv[1:]
```

there is no command for checking the installed version and switch between those versions.
What would be its solution ? Even I uninstalled and reinstalled everything but didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking a particular python version your device runs?

`python -version`

It is a good practise too to check what version of python is stored in the Environment variable (assuming your are running Windows OS). And change it (if need be) to reflect the exact python version you want :).

Comment: Yep I did Check ! python -V shows 3.9.11 and in env variable when I put path of 3.11.8 this version on top or another version then its changing the multiple version which is fine. But is it relevant to go to env variables and shift the path up and down ? Therefore we use "py -0" which is not working for me or "python --list" command to see my versions which is also not working.

Comment: Try to make further research in the use of  ```python -E``` command as it ignores python path in the environment variables. See if that would help solving your issue.